# Ошибка в программе поиска корней квадратного уравнения (C++)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, D;
    cout << "Введите коофициенты квадратного уравнения\n";
    cout << "a = ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b = ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "c = ";
    cin >> c;
    D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (D < 0)
    {
        cout << "Корни отсутствуют";
    }
    if (D == 0)
    {
        int x;
        x = -b/2a;
        cout << "Корень уравнения: " x;
    }
    if (D > 0)
    {
        int x1, x2;
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(D))/2a;
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(D))/2a;
        cout << "Корни уравнения: " x1 " и " x2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вот, уже и в самом С++ ошибки нашли :). Я все же исправлю заголовок...

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что у тебя все вычисления в целых числах вместо вещественных.

И не компилируется оно по той же причине.

Comment: вроде репутация большая а ответ слабенький ._.

Comment: @Lofectr. это правило самого быстрого стрелка на западе -  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 1):

Самая большая ошибка - это запись вида 2a, тут нет знаков, компилятор не понимает чего вы хотите.Также дело в том, что вы делите целое число на целое число, эта операция в результате также дает целое число в C++. Чтобы код работал верно вам необходимо сделать следующие замены:

```
1. заменить -b/2a на float(-b)/2*a
2. заменить (-b + sqrt(D))/2a на float(-b + sqrt(D))/2a
3. заменить (-b - sqrt(D))/2a на float(-b - sqrt(D))/2a
```